# calling a parameter of a parameter of a class through a method of that class

Tags: python, class

I have the following class:

```
class xyq(object):

    def __init__(self,param1,param2):
        self.param1=param1
        self.param2=param2
```

considering that an instance of xyq is:

```
    instance1=xyq(param1=110, param2=func1(x=10,y=20))
```

It is possible to have a method inside `class xyq` that references a parameter inside param2?
Such as:

```
method1(self):
    return self.param2.x
```

Or this is just possible to be called from an instance?

Basically I am going to receive an input with one of the parameters I am interested in is a funcion in which one of its sub parameters I would like to  use it for a method to output a table. In case this is not possible:

Any idea on how could I overcome this issue??

Comment: why are you using an `=` to set the parameters? It should just be `instance1 = xyq(110, func1(10, 20))`

Comment: @AllKnower Sometimes done to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is how classes work, and, in fact, that's the entire reason `self` is a parameter for instance methods.

In fact, when you do

```
instance1 = xyq(param1=110, param2=func1(x=10,y=10))
```

you're not directly setting those values. Rather the lines

```
self.param1 = param1
self.param2 = param2
```

in `xyq.__init__()` are setting those values. You could do `xyq(110, func1(x=10,y=10)` for the exact same effect.

Later, you can do either `instance1.param2.x` if you're outside the class, or `instance1.method1()`, and they'll return the same thing. In fact, when you do

```
self.param2.x
```

in `method1()`, you're literally referring to the same object as when you do `instance1.param2.x` outside of the method. That is, *when you call a method on an instance, the instance itself gets automatically passed as the `self` parameter* and you can use it accordingly.

---

If you want to have a more straightforward way to reference `instance1.param2.x` from outside the instance, you could modify `__init__()` to set it as another parameter:

```
self.param3 = self.param2.x
```

but another way to do something like this would be to [override `__getattribute()__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), customize its behavior in your specific cases, and have it just behave normally otherwise.

Comment: thank you for your response, could any decorator over the method could help to solve this issue??

Comment: I don't think a decorator is the solution, but there might be other ways to accomplish what you want (I'm still not 100% sure what that is, though)  - see my edited answer